# My problem is that my player is not attaching to the roof when he jumps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that my player(box) is not attaching itself when it jumps and reaches the roof(really long rectangle). There is a ground(really long rectangle) and a roof and the player is in between them with just enough room to jump that he reaches the roof. There are two box colliders and one of them is trigger and the collision field is slightly expanded.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Platform_Attach_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Player.transform.parent = transform;
            rb.mass = 0;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Player.transform.parent = null;
            
        }
    }
}
```

This code has worked for previous projects I have worked but I have been tweaking it for my current project. I have tried changing the mass for when my player jumps up and reaches the box collider with the trigger but then I realised I am just changing the mass of the roof so that's why it fell a few times then I tried looking on Youtube and forums for how to call a Gameobject's function from a particular script I couldn't find anything. So then I thought I was trying to do the impossible, as I've been coding for 6 months now.

So the bottom line is when my player jumps it's meant to get attached to the roof and when it jumps again it's meant to jump back on the ground and there is a script that keeps it moving constantly.

Comment: Lets do some debugging, can you add a Debug.Log statement to the OnTriggerEnter, and log the other gameobject and its tag? Maybe that doesnt exactly match "Player"!

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it now:)